# How to collect google map informations in java application?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the "Churches" nearby someplace, for example "Singapore".

Very similar with Google map: Search nearby----first use Google map to search one place, then click it and choose `"Search nearby"`, after that it display the related info's, images, locations.

I want to collect these information based Google map, insert them to my defined database. But I have no idea on how implementation it and what I need resort to?

Answer (score 1):

There's a developer's guide for [Maps Java API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_java.html). It will describe you how to use the maps using Java. For searching the stuff you need on the map, you'll probably need [this guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#Search) too.

Comment: are you sure that I can get the stuff by that guide?:)